# Prove that 1. $\kappa(x,y)$ is a symmetric bilinear form? 2. $\kappa([x,y],z)=\kappa(x,[y,z])$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, bilinear-form

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex Lie algebra. The Killing form on $\mathfrak g$ is defined by $\kappa(x,y)=tr(ad(x) \circ ad(y))$.

Now how to prove that

1. $\kappa(x,y)$ is a symmetric bilinear form?
2. $\kappa([x,y],z)=\kappa(x,[y,z])$

I am actually in between the trace and lie algebra cases. I have proved that $ad(X)Y=[X,Y]$. So do I have to calculate it on to the elementary matrices?

I am not getting any clue. Please help.

Comment: Isn't $ad(X)Y=[X,Y]$ the definition of the adjoint?

Comment: Yes, it is, I have mentioned that. Can I get any clue from that?

Comment: What puzzles me is that you say you have proved this fact. If it's the definition there's nothing to prove.

Comment: Sorry, for making you disappointed I haven't studied Humphreys. I am studying from Brian C Hall and $ad$ is defined as an induced operator from $Ad: G \to H$ where $G$ and $H$ are matrix lie algebra. So, $ad(X)(Y)=\frac{d}{dt}(Ad(e^{tX})(Y)=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{tX}Ye^{-tX})=XY-YX$ at $t=0$.

Comment: Sorry, if I would have disheartened you but I was unable to find a proof in Brian C Hall.

Comment: I have upvoted the question as I have also read Brian C Hall and could not remember to read about it. The question seems interesting and I was trying even but in vain. Maybe less experience in voting effects here a lot. I think he is also a newcomer like me, so I would prefer not to downvote him/her.

Comment: I have upvoted the question as I have seen this question with votes and I started finding a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ implies 1.

$ad([x,y])=ad(x)ad(y)-ad(y)ad(x)$ Jacobi identity.

$tr(ad([x,y])ad(z))=tr((ad(x)ad(y)-ad(y)ad(x))ad(z))$

$tr(adx(ad([y,z])=tr(ad(x)(ad(y)ad(z)-ad(z)ad(y))$

use $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ which implies that $tr(ad(y)(ad(x)ad(z))=tr(ad(y)(ad(x)ad(z))=tr((ad(x)ad(z))ad(y))$.